# Is the verb or verb in ing form is suited here?

Tags: sentence-construction

I have two ideas and want to put them into one construction.

> 1. The clusters representing objects are then extracted by introducing
>      set of shape constraints.
> 2. shape constraints describe the global shape
>      of an object.

after combining them,

> The clusters representing objects are then extracted by introducing
>   set of shape constraints (*describe/describing*) the global shape of an
>   object.

So, I am not sure what verb form should I used. i.e. either describe or describing. Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

> The clusters representing objects are then extracted by introducing a set of shape constraints that describe the global shape of an object.

or this:

> The clusters which represent objects are then extracted by introducing a set of shape constraints that describe the global shape of an object.